# How to ignore AndroidManifest errors when using apache ant?

Tags: android, ant, admob

When I build app in the Eclipse, all is ok, but when I try to build with the apache ant, I have got some errors:

```
[aapt] ...\AndroidManifest.xml:10: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'hardwareAccelerated' in package 'android'
[aapt] ...\AndroidManifest.xml:23: error: Error: String types not allowed (at 'configChanges' with value 'keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale').
```

I use the "uses-sdk" with minSDKVersion=7 (I need to run app on the Android 2.1 devices). When I remove "uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" values" from "configChanges" and remove "hardwareAccelerated", then ANT properly complete it's job, but AdMob do not work properly.

I know, that "uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" values first introduced in SDK API level 13, but when I use Eclipse to build app, all working good on Android 2.1.

I don't know what I should do ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the targetSDKVersion to 13?

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>
```

Comment: I read about this, but I can't understand, what it mean. In general, this will remove my problems with values in manifest, but also it will skip all checks for code and used API, and I can't be sure that my app will run on Android 2.1, or I need always test it on different Android versions.

Comment: The target sdk is always greater than or equal to the min: the min sdk is a strict subset of the target. If you want to fix your issues that's what you'll have to do. You SHOULD do the test that your code runs fine on 2.1 anyway.

Comment: I set the "android:targetSdkVersion" to "13", but, unfortunately, problem still exist.